# Accesing a value of model in object without specific property

Tags: java, class, encapsulation

I can get a total of items in the cart with a method "getTotalItemPrice" as you can see below.

However, I am not sure this is a good way or not to take get total price.

I know that I can set total value which had already calculated while creating an object. But getting a total value with a method is easy for me.

Please, share with me your recommendations about it.

```
public class CartModel {
    private List<ItemModel> items;

    public List<ItemModel> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<ItemModel> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public double getTotalItemPrice() {
        double totalPrice = 0.0;
        if (items != null && items.isEmpty()) {
            for (ItemModel item : items) {
                totalPrice += item.getPrice();
            }
        }
        return totalPrice;

    }
}



public class ItemModel {
    private String item;
    private double price;
    private String currency;

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you have makes more sense.  Calculate the total when it's needed, not when the object is constructed, or every time item is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few things:

1. The thing you are doing now – calculate the total when it's needed. This is perfectly fine in most cases.
2. The other thing you could do is create a field with the total value, and update it when an item is added or deleted. This acts as a sort of caching mechanism. However, this only makes sense if the collection is very expensive to traverse or the collection is very, very big. In trivial cases this is unnecessary.

---

By the way, I recommend to never leave a collection set to `null`, always initialize it, i.e. `private List<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>()` or something similar.

Second, you could just rewrite your `getTotalItemPrice` method as follows, using functional programming:

```
public double getTotalItemPrice() {
    return this.items.stream()
        .mapToDouble(item -> item.getPrice())
        .sum();
}
```

This creates a stream to walk over each element of `items`. First the item is mapped to its price, so it is transformed to a stream with `double`s, then we apply a *reduction operation*, summing all elements of the stream.